# Ruby On Rails - How to access a Child from its Parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, erb

I'm struggling to find a way to access a child attribute from its' parent. I have these two models:

```
class SuspendedCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :cases
end


class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :suspended_company
end
```

I want to access Case's name from a SuspendedCompany. In my SuspendedComany controller I have tried a join like this:

```
@case = Case.joins(:suspended_company).where(...)
```

Comment: You want all child's or one?

Comment: Do you have suspended_company object or do you want to load all case model data where they have suspended company?

Comment: I guess you are looking for this `@case = Case.joins(:suspended_company).pluck(:name)`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your problem is, but I think what you need is to use `includes` to fetch `Case`s with their related records of `SuspendedCompany` like: `Case.includes(:suspended_company).joins(:suspended_company).where(...)`

Comment: Title misspells "Ruby on Rails" as "Roby on Rails". Can you change it?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are finding a company in your `SuspendedCompany` controller by something like this

```
@suspended_company = SuspendedCompany.find(params[:id])
```

In order to have access to cases in your view without additional queries you can transform it into

```
@suspended_company = SuspendedCompany.includes(:cases).find(params[:id])
```

And then in your view you can do

```
@suspended_company.cases.map(&:name)
```

Answer (score 3):

In the controller index for SuspendedCompany write

```
@cases = @SuspendedCompany.cases
```

And in the index view for SuspendedCompany

```
<% @cases.each do |case| %>
   <%= case.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: In the controller, I'm having an undefined method error for 'cases'